# Sending an HTML email (links are not working)

Tags: php, html, email

```
$to = $user_email;
$subject = "Test Notification\r\n"; 
$from = "Test Notification<noreply@test.com>";

$headers = "From: ".$from;
$headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$mail_content = "<html><body>"; 
$mail_content .= "<h4><strong>Hello ".$user_login.",</strong></h4>";
$mail_content .= "<div>". html_entity_decode($message)."</div>"; 
$mail_content .= "</body></html>"; 

mail($to,$subject,$mail_content,$headers);
```

Hello I have this code to send email.

im sending this sample email.

```
<p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eget blandit dui. Integer imperdiet malesuada sem a aliquet. Vivamus ut dui in erat mollis dapibus. Morbi rutrum turpis nec laoreet mattis. Maecenas in ligula augue. Proin aliquet nisl vitae aliquam sodales. Vestibulum blandit rutrum ligula sit amet ullamcorper. Aliquam eget nunc placerat, sagittis nibh ac, sagittis ligula. Curabitur et turpis ac dui consequat aliquet a vitae nibh. Etiam vitae nisl dui. Integer non tortor sit amet urna faucibus lobortis. Nulla tempus, metus et viverra ullamcorper, libero massa lacinia sapien, ut facilisis massa ipsum vel ligula. Quisque pretium arcu lectus, vel pretium diam convallis sit amet. Vestibulum tempor est sapien, at mattis nulla tincidunt et. Curabitur eu ipsum id tellus laoreet porttitor.
</p>

<a href="www.google.com">Visit my site</a>
```

When I check my email the `Visit my site` is not a link.

How do I solve this problem? while all html code has been converted properly, only the links are not.

Comment: That's probably got to do with the e-mail client, try some other clients and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using any protocol there, you will need `http://` or `https://` so your URL is *relative* instead of *absolute*, so it needs to be

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Visit my site</a>
       ---^---
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You need to add http or https protocol, Otherwise it consider the url as a local resource

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Visit my site</a>
      ....^
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add protocols like `http://` or `ftp://` based on sites in front or just append `//` like this

```
 <a href="//www.google.com" target="_blank">Visit my site</a>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xdckj/4/)